# how to print coordinates of an object on terminal?

Tags: c++, opencv

i am beginner in opencv. i have a code written in opencv and c++ which is detecting geometric objects like square, triangle, circle etc with the help of camera.  i am trying to print the coordinates and name of detected objects on the windows terminal and on the camera output screen.i could not figure out how to do it.
 here is my code

```
void setLabel(cv::Mat& im, const std::string label, std::vector<cv::Point>& contour)
{
        int fontface = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
        double scale = 0.4;
        int thickness = 1;
        int baseline = 0;

        cv::Size text = cv::getTextSize(label, fontface, scale, thickness, &baseline);
        cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contour);

        cv::Point pt(r.x + ((r.width - text.width) / 2), r.y + ((r.height + text.height) / 2));
        cv::rectangle(im, pt + cv::Point(0, baseline), pt + cv::Point(text.width, -text.height), CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
        cv::putText(im, label, pt, fontface, scale, CV_RGB(0,0,0), thickness, 8);

}
```

and i am writing the condition like this

```
 if (approx.size() == 3)
 {
    setLabel(dst, "TRIANGLE", contours[i]);    // Triangles

 }
```

thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: **detecting geometric objects like square, triangle, circle etc**, where in your code has this been done? Because if you are using a detector then you should be getting the detections as coordinates returned as results.

Comment: Please check the code as mention below

Comment: you have to edit your question with the code. Please don't post it as an answer.